# Generating Json String from Avro Schema and Data Object

Tags: java, json, serialization, avro

I have an Avro Schema (org.apache.avro.Schema) and a data object. I want to serialize the object into a JSON string according to the schema. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get the fields in the Avro schema and use them as a filter for custom serializer. See https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria

Answer (score 2):

You can use a JsonEncoder:

```
public String serialiseToJson(MyAvroType value) {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final Encoder jsonEncoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(MyAvroType.getClassSchema(), baos);
    final DatumWriter<MyAvroType> writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(MyAvroType.class);

    writer.write(value, jsonEncoder);
    jsonEncoder.flush();

    return new String(baos.toByteArray());
}
```

Comment: Correct. However, I get the field type ("string" here) next to the value, which should not be the case in conventional JSON: "address__Id":{"string":"215164"} Any idea how to remove that?

Comment: @Arman You need to use a **non-nullable**, non-union string field for `address__Id` https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/#json-encoding